# How to throw SoapFault in .net WebService?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, soap

I'm implementing a .Net Webservice (not WCF) and need to throw SoapFault under certain circumstances, according to the protocol I should send a custom fault which will include an InternalFaultCode element.

I've tried throwing a SoapFaultException with my own FaultObject as detail, but the client gets the .ToString() of that Exception under the faultstring element.

```
// This is the method I call every time I want to throw a FaultException
private void ThrowFault(string internalCode, string errorMsg)
{
    throw new SoapException(errorMsg, SoapException.ServerFaultCode, new FaultException<InternalFaultDataType>(new InternalFaultDataType("Server", errorMsg, internalCode)));
}

// This is just an example
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
[return: System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("authenticateUserResponse")]
public AuthenticateUserResponse AuthenticateUser(AuthenticateUserRequest data)
{
    var x = User.GetByUserName(data.username);
    if(null != x) {
        // Check auth
        return AuthenticateUserResponse.fromUser(x);
    } else {
        this.ThrowFault("INVALID_CREDENTIALS", "Invalid username or password");
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding some sample code might help us

Comment: I'm not sure what to show you since I don't know how to throw my own SoapFaultException from the web service. Right now I'm throwing one of those but clearly it's being caught and re thrown I don't know how.

Comment: so could you please put that code.. So that we also can anlayse

Comment: I added the code, I cleaned it so it's shorter!

Answer (score 0):

I finally found what I was looking for, there are few links that walked me through the process of doing this the correct way.

Basically the process is:

- Extend SoapExtension class and override the ProcessMessage() method.
- In ProcessMessage(), add special handler code for message stage of SoapMessageStage.AfterSerialize.
- Modify the web service's web.config file and add a  node to  section.

[User Friendly ASP.NET Exception Handling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8049/User-Friendly-ASP-NET-Exception-Handling)

[Throwing Better .NET Exceptions with SOAP and HTTP](http://blog.codinghorror.com/throwing-better-net-exceptions-with-soap-and-http/)